# Include the POM version in Doxygen?

Tags: maven, doxygen, pom.xml

I use Doxygen to document my project. My project uses Maven and thus contains a POM file with a version.

Is it possible to reuse this version number as PROJECT_NUMBER in Doxygen?

Answer (score 0):

Maven has the ability to filter files and replace Maven properties with actual values. If your doxygen configuration file is in your `src/main/resources/...` path, you can simply add:

```xml
<project>
  <build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>
    </resources>
  </build>
</project>
```

Then you can reference `${project.version}` in your doxygen file and it will be replaced with the version number.

Comment: OK I note that but the doxygen configuration file is not a "source file". Thus I have to put my doxygen config file as ressource and then aplly a filter on it ?